# Vue.js - Vuetify how to get rounded corners on cards?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to get rounded corners on a v-card as I can get on a  btn, but it does not seems to be possible ?

I used

```
<v-card round class="elevation-0">
```

Here is my template

```
    <template>
        <section id="section2">
          <v-parallax :src="require('../../assets/images/members.jpeg')" height="380">
            <v-layout column align-center justify-center>
              <v-flex xs12 sm12 md8>
                <v-card round class="elevation-0">
                    <v-card-title primary-title class="layout justify-center">
                      <h3 v-html="$t('lang.views.home.section4.thank_you')" ></h3>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text>
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-parallax>
        </section>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`v-card` has rounded corners by default. It does not provide a prop named `round` to make it have more rounded corners.

If you want to have more rounded corners as compared to the default then add a custom css class to `v-card`

```
<v-card class="rounded-card">
```

#### css

```
.rounded-card{
    border-radius:50px;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKXEdb?editors=1100)

Comment: Furthermore, you can use the built in css classes like 'rounded' and 'rounded-0' etc.

Comment: Just an addition, the card has "shaped" props which applies a large border radius but only on the top left and bottom right of the card.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to update Vamsi Krishna's answer. Vuetify now provides since v2.3 border utilities to quickly style the border-radius of any element.

To minimize custom CSS and make your Vue app more consitent, you may now use `.rounded-xs`, `.rounded`, `.rounded-lg` or `.rounded-xl` classes as specified [in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/border-radius/#rounded-corners):

```html
<v-card class="rounded-lg">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
<v-card class="rounded-xl">
```

For round card in `Vue.js`:

```
Other Class{
.rounded-0
.rounded-sm
.rounded-md
.rounded-xl
.rounded-pill
.rounded-circle
}
```

Reference Link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/border-radius/#usage

Answer (score 2):

v-card has a prop called shaped which applies border radius to top left and bottom right, but we can add our own border radius like this

```
<v-card shaped class="rounded-corner"></v-card>
```

CSS

```
.rounded-corner{
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border radius to style border-radiuses of any element. In Vuetify's official documentation they show its use in divs.
For instance, the below code gives you a rounded circle.

`<div class="pa-7 secondary rounded-circle d-inline-block"></div>`

Here's the documentation link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/border-radius/#removing-border-radius